# Gridview generating Select column with AutoGenerateSelectButton="false"

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP:Gridview that is generating a select column even though AutoGenerateSelectButton = "false". Here is the declaration:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdAssessments" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CssClass="gridview" 
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even" 
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="false"
    DataKeyNames="ReportId" 
    AllowSorting="True" Width="1000px"
    OnSelectedIndexChanging="grdAssessments_SelectedIndexChanging"
    OnSorting="grdAssessments_Sorting"
    OnRowCommand="grdAssessments_RowCommand"
    OnRowDataBound="grdAssessments_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even" />
    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
onclick="showEmployeeEdit('<%# Eval("EmployeeNumber") %>')" title="Edit">Edit</a>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateCreated" SortExpression="DateCreated">
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDateCreated" runat="server" />
               </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
...
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is the resultant gridview... with the Select column that I want to get rid of.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was: grdAssessments.AutoGenerateSelectButton = false;

I have no idea WHY this solves the problem, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark: Don't wire up the `OnSelectedIndexChanging` event. Why would you want that without a `Select Button` of some type?